# Turn off the headers for the rendered window

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, 3d-view

I am using python script to render the image. I only want to show the IMAGE_EDITOR area( I think the rendered image gets shown in IMAGE_EDITOR area). It should show only the rendered image.

So basically I am trying to do 2 things here

- Render the image
- Show only the area with the image.

I hope I am clear on this. I tried to render image by -

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'INFO':
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.render.render(override, use_viewport=True)
        break
```

But it doesn't work.

**EDIT**: So as iKlsR told, I used a differnt display mode. I am able to get the whole rendered image using

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.display_mode = 'FULL'
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'INFO':
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.render.view_show('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        bpy.ops.render.render(override, use_viewport=True)
        break
```

However, I need just the rendered area. Not the headers . How can I make them turn off?

Comment: In regards to your edit. I'm not sure how to entirely disable headers. There is a screen layout called _3d view full_ that does this somehow for the 3d viewport, you could investigate from there.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking, you can get the same results by choosing *New Window* or *Fullscreen* in the *Render* panel under the *Display* drop-down list.

Choosing *New Window* will give you a tad bit more screen estate by not having the *Info* header. Hover over the list with the current selection for the python equivalent if you want to use it in a script.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks.

Here, I did ``bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.display_mode = 'WINDOW'``. But when I did ``bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport=True)`` nothing happens.

Comment: @iamkhush Looking at the [docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_5/bpy.ops.render.html#bpy.ops.render.render), I am not sure _what_ is supposed to happen.

Comment: Yeah, I also tried bpy.ops.render.view_show(), but still it isnt working. I used the --debug-all. I think its not able to set the screen with the rendered output.